# Make Complex Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

How to make complex chrome app like Cut the Rope

`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cut-the-rope/jfbadlndcminbkfojhlimnkgaackjmdo`

or Funky Karts

`https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/funky-karts/jbgibbcljlbkkeaogjofolcbakcokmie`

It's javascript or something else?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will definitely have to us javascript but for 2d graphics you will have to use canvas. For Cut the Rope you have to use a javascript physics engine library too like
[link]http://brm.io/matter-js/

So techniques you will need:

- HTML
- CSS
- Javascript
- Canvas
- Libraries and frameworks which will make these techniques easier to use.